# Centering text in a text box in a scroll view Corona SDK

Tags: lua, scrollview, coronasdk

I'm making a mobile app for a project and I've kind of hit a wall. I've had no problems implementing a scroll view and inserting a text box and other objects into it, but centering the text inside of the scroll view has proved a nightmare.

I'm not sure what other options to try, I was wondering whether anyone could help. I've attached the part of the code concerned below.

```
local widget = require( "widget" )

-- ScrollView listener
local function scrollListener( event )

local phase = event.phase
if ( phase == "began" ) then print( "Scroll view was touched" )
elseif ( phase == "moved" ) then print( "Scroll view was moved" )
elseif ( phase == "ended" ) then print( "Scroll view was released" )
end

-- In the event a scroll limit is reached...
if ( event.limitReached ) then
    if ( event.direction == "up" ) then print( "Reached bottom limit" )
    elseif ( event.direction == "down" ) then print( "Reached top limit" )
    elseif ( event.direction == "left" ) then print( "Reached right limit" )
    elseif ( event.direction == "right" ) then print( "Reached left limit" )
    end
end

return true
end

-- Create the widget
local scrollView = widget.newScrollView
{
    top = 50,
    left = 10,
    right = 10,
    width = 300,
    height = 388,
    scrollWidth = 600,
    scrollHeight = 800,
     topPadding = 120,
     bottomPadding = 50, 
     leftPadding = 50, 
     rightPadding = 50,
     horizontalScrollDisabled = true,
     verticalScrollDisabled = false,
    listener = scrollListener

}

local lotsOfText = "Ransomware is a form of malware. Malware (also known as 
malicious software) refers to a program that is created with the intent of 
causing harm, this damage could take a range of forms, from destructive (such 
as the deletion of files) to compromising the confidentiality or integrity of 
the victim’s data or system(s)." 

local options = {
text = lotsOfText,
x = display.contentCenterX,
y = 200,
fontSize = 16,
align = "center"
}

local lotsOfTextObject = display.newText( lotsOfText, 0, 0, 275, 0, "Arial", 
16)
lotsOfTextObject:setTextColor( 0, 0, 0 )
lotsOfTextObject.x = display.contentCenterX
lotsOfTextObject.y = display.contentCentery
scrollView:insert(lotsOfTextObject)

end
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things are going on here.  First I want to point out that although you are setting your x position and centre aligning the text in options you are not using that table and instead using the legacy syntax.
See https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newText.html#syntax for how to use the new syntax.

To centre the text in the scroll view you want to set your x position to half the scroll width of your scrollview.

```
local options = {
    text = lotsOfText,
    x = display.contentCenterX,
    y = 200,
    fontSize = 16,
    align = "center"
}
local lotsOfTextObject = display.newText(options)
lotsOfTextObject:setTextColor( 0, 0, 0 )

--The following sets your text to be in the middle of the scrollable area
lotsOfTextObject.x = 300 

--The following sets your text to be in the middle of the viewable area
lotsOfTextObject.x = scrollView.width / 2 

--The following sets your text to be at the top of the viewable area
lotsOfTextObject.y = 0
lotsOfTextObject.anchorY = 0

scrollView:insert(lotsOfTextObject)
```

Comment: Thank you! "scrollView.width / 2" worked like a charm. Yea i've realised after a few days of coding, this is the first time i've used corona in over a year so i'm a little rusty to say the least.